# OpenFileDialog() locks the folder

Tags: c#, silverlight

I use `OpenFileDialog()` in my Silverlight application. When I select a file using `ShowDialog()` it simply locks the file until I close my application.

I am not able to rename or delete the folder when the application is running (silverlight application in browser)

If I try to select any other file in any another folder, I am able to rename the previous folder. It seems it is releasing the handle.

My goal: I want to rename/delete the folder in filesystem (manually) once I finished uploading.

I know it is not possible to point `OpenFileDialog()` to some other folder from code. Any pointers?

Btw, this is the windows error message:

> The action can't be completed because
>   the folder is open in another program.
>   Close the folder and try again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The follow fixed it

```
Stream fileStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
if (fileStream != null)
{
   ...
   fileStream.Close();
}
```

By closing the stream my problem went away... :P

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  OFD in Silverlight returns an open file stream, and you've got to close it before, well, it gets closed :-).  A slightly better pattern is to declare the Stream fileStream outside of a try/catch block, and then put the "if (fileStream !=null)..." bit inside the finally{} block.

Answer (score 2):

```
using(var fileStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
   // do your stuff

}
```

this will close the stream and fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old thread, but I've experienced the same problem and found some odd behavior in the OpenFileDialog.

The problem is not that the FileDialog isn't disposed correctly or that it's not releasing the resources. The problem is that the FileDialog changes the current directory to the directory the user chooses.

This won't happen in every scenario but I've managed to reproduce the error using the ShowHelp property (using .NET Framework 4.7):

```
var before = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // result: The directory the application started from

using (var fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
{
    ShowHelp = true
})
{
    if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

var after = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // result: The directory the user opened the file from
```

It may not only be the ShowHelp property that does this but this was how I could reproduce it (and it sure seems like a bug to me).

As Vyacheslav writes we can avoid this behavior by setting RestoreDirectory to true.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it the way windows file system work - you can't rename folder while having some open file handles inside. Make sure that you release all resources from folder(File.Close() etc.) before trying to rename it.

Comment: Yes, I release all resources. And I do not have any problem in renaming the files (even selected files).

Comment: All resources, do you also .Dispose the filedialog ? .Close it is not enough.

Comment: @nos:  Ordinarily .Close and .Dispose are synonymous on Disposable objects, however in this case OpenFileDialog has neither.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones If you are calling .ShowDialog, Close and Dispose are not synonyms. I'm assuming the OP is using System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog - though being Silverlight that might not be the case.

Comment: @nos: No this is a silverlight question OpenFileDialog is quite a different beast.

Comment: SL OpenFileDialog is different. It doesn't have Dispose() or Close()

Answer (score 0):

Having assigned null to all variables holding a reference to OpenFileDialog and any FileInfo references or in code where all that stuff is out of scope, then try this:-

```
GC.Collect();
```

Its a very draconian thing to do and I wouldn't normally recommend it.  If it doesn't fix your problem get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such behaviour set RestoreDirectory property value to true.
Here you can read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx

Comment: This has nothing to do with locking.